# Imperfect HTML-encoding in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding

I'm using the asp mvc 3. When I build my views using the default html-helpers there is a problem with html-encoding in tag-attributes: The "greater-than"-sign isn't encoded.

So this code

```
<%: Html.TextBox("TestText", "<Test>") %>
```

produces this output

```
<input id="TestText" name="TestText" type="text" value="&lt;Test>" />
```

Is there any reason why the value-attribute isn't full encoded or is this a bug?
Or is there any way how to use a full encoding even in tag-attributes?

Thanx,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you misunderstood the `<%:` tag. The `<%:` tag only encodes normal `string`, not `HtmlString` as returned by `Html.TextBox` helper.

**Example:**

```
<%: Html.TextBox("TestText", "<Test>") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("TestText2", "<Test>") %>
```

Both statements return the same text value as mentioned in question. Now consider this statement.

```
<%: "<Test>" %>
```

This statement encodes, as now normal string is passed.

**EDIT:**

After checking the [source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) of MVC, [HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx) is called under the hood. It **minimally** converts a string to an HTML-encoded string.

Comment: No - I don't misunderstood the <%: tag resspectively the <%= tag.
But I wonder why a <%: "<Test>" %> is encoded correctly while the value in my example is encoded to "&lt;Test>". I don't expect that the hole tag is encoded - I just expect that the value of an attribute is full encoded.

Comment: Thanx. That's what I was looking for - even if I don't understand why they don't use HtmlEncode. So I have to build my own helpers which do a full encoding.

Answer (score 1):

"<test>" is being HTML encoded. The greater-than character '>' by itself is harmless, which is why it wasn't converted into &gt;

Comment: Even it is harmless, I can't understand, why MS uses two encoding-types. The Server.HTMLEncode works as expected - but it seems that they use another function here.
My problem is that every application we publish over the internet in our company must pass a security-check. And the guys doing this check rate this fragmental encoding as a vulnerability. And no chance to discuss this...

Comment: Maybe not worth waking up a very old thread, but MSDN says that `HtmlEncode` is orders of magnitude slower than `HtmlAttributeEncode`, which is why it is not used everywhere.